# Object type changes on import/export in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have been banging up against this for several hours now and I'm hoping that someone can help point me in the right direction.

I'm developing a few custom PowerShell cmdlets, and one of the supporting classes is a User object.  Several of my cmdlets either emit or consume List.

This has worked very well so far, but I hit a serious snag when I tried to serialize one of the lists.  The export seems to work fine; I look at the file (csv, clixml, etc.) and it looks the way I expect it to with type User.  However, when I re-import it, the type seems to change to CSV:Class.User or Deserialized.Class.User.  Obviously, this causes a problem when it's fed into a cmdlet that expects the standard User class.

If there a good way to fix this?  I suspected that changing my cmdlets to expect some Interface instead of List would probably do the trick, but I can't figure out what interface that should be.  And I can find no switch to the import methods to specify class names.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to PowerShell's extended type system. :-)  BTW you will also get back state-only deserialized objects when your objects are passed across a remoting session.  You can query the PSObject's TypeNames collection looking for Deserialized.Class.User to determine if you have a deserialized version of your type. Sames goes for the CSV version.  You could create a couple of factory methods or clone style constructors on your User class that takes a PSObject that is some type of User (CSV or Deserialized) and then create a regular Class.User object. Just be aware that certain operations may not make sense in the deserialization case.  For instance, using a Process object as an example, you can call Kill on a Process object and if the object came from the same machine that would work (assuming correct privs).  However, if you were to call Kill on a process object from another machine, that's not going to work - hence the special `deserialized` objects that are primarily just data (property) containers.